# Webpage returns blank when imported JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm implementing a JavaScript function that displays a schedule block on a calendar view, given its starting time and end time.

Here's the function that calculates the length of the block to be placed, given the two time parameters:

```
function calculateBlockLength(startTime, endTime) {
  const start = stringTimetoDate(startTime);
  const end = stringTimetoDate(endTime);
  const startHour = start.getHours();
  const endHour = end.getHours();
  const startMinutes = start.getMinutes();
  const endMinutes = end.getMinutes();
  let startBlock = 1;
  let length = 1;

  if (startHour > 10) {
    for (let i = 10; i < startHour; i++) {
      startBlock += 12;
    }
  }

  if (startHour >= 10 && endHour <= 22) {
    for (let i = startHour; i < endHour; i++) {
      length += 12;
    }
    if (Math.abs(endMinutes - startMinutes) === 30) {
      length += 6;
    }
  }

  return [startTime, startBlock, length];
}
```

Now I imported the function on another JavaScript file which returns the calendar view.

```
import calculateBlockLength from './utilities.js';

let [testStart, testSB, testLength] = calculateBlockLength('11:00AM', '3:00PM');
console.log(testStart);
console.log(testSB);
console.log(testLength);
```

When the webpage is locally run, it returns a blank page, while there are no ongoing errors. The page is written using TailwindCSS, and uses the values returned from the function `calculateBlockLength()`.

```
export default function WeeklyView() {
    return (
        <ol
        className="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-7 sm:pr-8"
        style={{gridTemplateRows: '1.75rem repeat(288, minmax(0, 1fr)) auto',}}>
                
            <SessionBlock
             dayIndex={3}
             start={testSB}
             end={testLength}
             textColor={'text-blue-500'}
             sessionName={'Test 1'}
             sessionStartTime={'10:00AM'}/>
        </ol>
    )
}
```

Do note the other unnecessary TailwindCSS components are removed from this code for simplicity.

Comment: I never had to use `import` or `export` for any JavaScript files on any HTML files. Perhaps do on your website `<script src="/first.js"></script><script src="/second.js"></script>` in the order that each JavaScript file needs each other in. Lemme know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any output in your browser console? Generally if a webpage is returning a blank page, there are some console errors alongside it.

Edit: Wait are you exporting the `calculateBlockLength` function? Because it doesnt look like you are from these code snippets. That could be crashing the page.

Comment: @TomLV no the ```calculateBlockLength``` function is not being exported; it's only being referenced from another JavaScript file. The ```WeeklyView()``` function is being exported.